# Should I have separate rest controller for a dependent entity

Tags: java, rest

There are two entities in my spring boot app: `Dealer`, `Car`

A `Car` cannot live without being owned by a `Dealer`.

Right now, I have two sets of endpoints (i.e. two controller classes): `DealerController`, `CarController`

`DealerController` handles `CRUD` operations for `Dealer` entities. `CarController` handles `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `READ` operations for `Car` entities.

My question is regarding the `CREATE` operation for `Car`. The endpoint takes in the id for the `Dealer` and the `POST` request body would be the `Car` information.

Should I put it under `DealerController` or `CarController` ?

Comment: You should put it under CarController .As you already created dealer and now it is the time to create car for that dealer.

Comment: Yes, you should put in under `CarController` since you dont really change table `Dealer` while invoking `Car`

Comment: If the scenario is thought in OO space, a `Dealer` cannot create a `Car`. He can only deal with existing `Car`(s). Ideally, a `Dealer` should access some `CarWarehouse` or `CarFactory` to `GET` a `Car`.

Comment: What if there was `User` instead of `Car` and `Group` instead of `Delaer`, and the `User` entity could live without being owned by a `Group`. Then we should put `Add Member` endpoint in the `GroupController` or `UserController` ?

Comment: `User` and `Group` scenario is slightly different when compared to `Car` and `Dealer` scenario. A `User` can request a `Group` member to add him in if the `Group` is private. If it's public, he can add himself in. In former case, `Group` has to expose `/addMember` API and in later case, `Group` has to expose `/register` API. But a `Car` cannot add or register itself with a `Dealer`. `Dealer` has to ask someone to get a Dealership of a `Car`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both controllers should be present as they will be used for specific operations.

The DealerController will be responsible for,

- Adding new dealers /dealers - POST
- Updating dealer details /dealers/2 - PUT
- Getting list of dealers - /dealers - GET
- Getting details of a particular dealer /dealers/2 - GET
- Deleting a dealer - /dealers/2 - DELETE
- etc.

The CarController will be responsible for,

- Adding new cars /cars - POST
- Updating car details - /cars/1 - PUT
- Getting list of all cars /cars - GET
- Getting list of all cars by dealer /cars?dealerId=2 /GET
- Getting details of a particular car /cars/1 - GET
- Deleting a car - /cars/1 - DELETE
- etc.

Your end point for CarController should not have the dealerId in it if you strictly want to go by RESTful conventions. When adding a new car, the request body should contain the JSON representation of the car attributes and the dealerId since every car can have only one dealerId

e.g.

```
{
    "dealerId": 2,
    "manufacturer": "bmw",
    "color": "white",
    "model": "320d"
}
```

Accordingly the model class for car should have the dealerId or the dealer object as its attribute, depending on how much detail you want.

Comment: And may I know why you don't pass the delaerId as a request parameter just like how you defined it in "Getting a list of all cars by dealer" ?

Comment: I meant you don't pass it as part of the endpoint URL. You can use it in query parameters or request body if you please and design the API to use it like a filter parameter on all records returned by the api

Comment: is there a special reason you don't like to pass it as a part of the URL ?

Comment: I go by RESTful conventions when designing the end point URL. It is important to distinguish between the end point URL and query string parameters. Anything after the ? are the query string parameters. They can be used to filter data based on what the end point URL returns. So while /cars will return all cars, /cars?dealerId=1 will return all cars with dealerId as 1. I dont know how else you would represent it more clearly in the URL. If you meant /cars/dealers/1 then I would submit that dealers are not a subset of cars and hence the URL formation is incorrect only from a convention standpoint

Answer (score 1):

As the operation is about creating a `Car`, it concerns the `Car` entity mainly. Hence, following the guidelines of *separation of concerns* and *high coupling* in *OOP*, it needs to be placed inside the `CarController`.